# DataGridView not able to order "displayindex"

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm having trouble with ordering the columns of a datagridview.

At first I was getting an error with a null exception but was able to get around it by try catching it.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
Oracle.Connection();
Oracle.getThings();
}
catch (Exception err)
{
MessageBox.Show("Error --- " + err.ToString(), "Error");
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = Oracle.dataTable;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
col.HeaderText = "chck";
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
try
{
organizeColumns();
}
catch (NullReferenceException r)
{
r.ToString();
}

}

private void organizeColumns()
{
dataGridView1.Columns["col10"].DisplayIndex = 0;
dataGridView1.Columns["col9"].DisplayIndex = 1;
dataGridView1.Columns["col8"].DisplayIndex = 2;
dataGridView1.Columns["col7"].DisplayIndex = 3;
dataGridView1.Columns["col6"].DisplayIndex = 4;
dataGridView1.Columns["col5"].DisplayIndex = 5;
dataGridView1.Columns["col4"].DisplayIndex = 6;
dataGridView1.Columns["col3"].DisplayIndex = 7;
dataGridView1.Columns["col2"].DisplayIndex = 8;
dataGridView1.Columns["col1"].DisplayIndex = 9;
dataGridView1.Columns["chck"].ReadOnly = false;
}
```

I have tried setting visibility to false.
I have tried to set the autogeneratecolumns to false which I found from googling that would do the trick but no luck for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not add columns as per your choice in the grid using the designer and assign the data source?

Comment: The way I have it now works...just can't order it or set the checkbox to ReadOnly = false...for some reason it still won't let me edit it or check it. I have also read that f you set the autogenerate to true first and then false it should work but this is not the case with me for some reason.

Comment: Find out what is the exact error? What is the Exception?

Comment: hmm it says it is not set to an instance of an object?

Comment: Is the column `chck` exists in the datasource? Check all the columns if they exists in the `Oracle.dataTable` for good

Comment: Oracle.dataTable is what I get back from the db and I add the chk column it is a checkbox column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100056/discussion-between-robertc-and-irshad).